# How to change the tab color when i click on tab

Tags: jquery, html

I had three tabs

1. Timeline
2. Celebration
3. Profile

when i click on timeline , it should shown with white color and other 2 tabs should be in yellow color. Like that alternative for all

But my coding not working , if i click celebration the colors not changed

Sample image

[image]

**Script**

```
$("#tab a").click(function() { 

 $(".listmenu").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='images/loader.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
    var id = this.href;
    var linkid = this.id;
    $('.tab'+linkid).addClass('men');
    $('.tab'+linkid).removeClass('color');

    $.ajax({ url: id, success: function(html) {

        $(".listmenu").empty().append(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

HTML & PHP

```
            <div class="col-12">
                 <div class="col-2 tab11 men" id="tab"><a href="" id="11" > TIMELINE</a></div>
                 <div class="col-2 tab22 color" id="tab" ><a href=""   id="22">CELEBRATION</a></div>
                 <div class="col-2 tab33 color" id="tab"><a href="" id="33">  PROFILE </a></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: same id `tab` in 3 divs?

Comment: check https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: @Joygive-Kalai please check the answer which i gave.. just by using css.. you can implement the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all

i just add the below line in script

```
$('.tab11 , .tab22, .tab33').addClass('color');
```

Now i got the accurate output. Thanks to all

```
    $("#tab a").click(function() { 

      $(".listmenu").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='images/loader.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
      var id = this.href;
      var linkid = this.id;
      $('.tab11 , .tab22, .tab33').addClass('color');

      $('.tab'+linkid).removeClass('color');
      $('.tab'+linkid).addClass('men');

      $.ajax({ url: id, success: function(html) {

        $(".listmenu").empty().append(html);
        }
      });
      return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 div with the same id. You must have to use a class instead of an id if you have multiple element with the same id value. ANd then retrieve the value of this class with jQuery('this').attr('class')

Comment: I got the output . I posted here. Thank you

Comment: No problem, glad to help you.